# How to remove 'send a message' option from Birthdays on Facebook

Tags: facebook

Whenever a friend has birthday, it is visible on our timeline as "[friend's name]'s birthday is today." When you click on that, a popup window opens and if they have not set the privacy for timeline as "Only me", you can write a birthday wish on the friend's timeline, but if they have set privacy for timeline, "Friends' Birthdays" shows an option to send a message as "Send [friend's name] a message".

I want to remove this "Send a message" option for my case. I want my birthday to be shown to my friends but they should not be able to write on my wall or send me a message.

How can I remove that message option (red circle in below image)?

[image]